# Auto paste clipboard jquery after click on input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ruby-on-rails-plugins

How I can set auto paste clipboard, when input is active ?
Is it possible to do it when page is ready ?

Comment: what would you plan on using this for in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing an automatically triggered paste event from a browser standpoint is a security risk so browsers don't support it. Using JavaScript you can manipulate the on paste event but that's obviously after the fact.

Here's an altered fiddle from a similar post http://jsfiddle.net/5bNx4/287/

it shows the `$(ele).on("paste")` event in action if you're interested.